# Destroying embeded objects when destroying the main object

Tags: php

I'd like to destroy an object and the intern objects in it. Why the example below is not working:

```
<?php
class I
{
    public $elt = 'hello world!!';
    public function __destruct()
    {
        var_dump('I: destroyed');
    }
}

class A
{
    public $val1=1;
    public $val2=2;
    public $val3=3;
    public $val4=4;
    public $i;
    public function __construct($i)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        var_dump('A destroyed');
        unset($this->i);
    }
}

$i = new I();
$a = new A($i);
unset($a);
var_dump($i);
```

OUTPUT:

```
  string(11) "A destroyed"
  object(I)#1 (1) { ["elt"]=> string(13) "hello world!!" }
  string(12) "I: destroyed"
```

How come I didn't get the notice `Undefined variable: i`?
And how come the message of the destructor of the class I is displayed after my var_dump of $i?

**UPDATE**

The thing is that I have a main object, this object has to purge/refresh its nested objects at the end of each iteration of a loop.

Comment: Note that it isn't neccesary to delete an nested object. At the end of the script the objects will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Actually I have to because my main object is used inside a loop, and it's necessary that I purge all nested objects

Comment: And do you still want to use the main object after purging the nested objects?

Comment: Also if you want to refresh your nested objects you should't use destruct because it will kill your main object. You can't refresh nested objects of a killed object.

Comment: No actually my main object should never be destroyed into the loop (but after). Into the loop I need to refresh nested objects with new values of the current iteration. The example I gave isn't perfect. @axiac seems to do what I want. thxs a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's talk about the four lines of code:

```
$i = new I();
$a = new A($i);
unset($a);
var_dump($i);
```

The first line creates an object of type `I` and stores a reference to it in variable `$i` (PHP objects are always assigned as references, you need to use the operator `clone` to create a copy).

The second line passes `$i` to the constructor of class `A` and that creates another reference to the same object, stored in `$a->$i`.

The third line destroys the object of type `A`; this removes the second reference to the object of type `I` but it does not affect the first one; the variable `$i` still holds it.

The fourth line dumps the content of variable `$i` that was never unset. It is the object of type `I` created on the first line.

If you want to destroy the object of type `I` when the object of type `A` is destroyed then make sure there is no other reference to it. This can be accomplished by either creating the object of type `I` in the constructor of class `A` or by removing all the references to `$i` after it was passed to the constructor of class `A`. Adding `unset($i);` after `$a = new A($i);` will do the job.

Comment: Sounds perfect. So you're suggesting that I keep the destructor of the class A as it is.

Comment: You don't really need the destructor of class `A`. With or without it, when the objects of type `A` are destructed their references to objects of type `I` are removed anyway. Keeping or removing it is just a matter of personal preferences in this case. You can keep them for debug and remove them when you are sure the objects are destroyed when you want them to be destroyed and no later than that.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP document: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Destructors called during the script shutdown have HTTP headers
>   already sent. The working directory in the script shutdown phase can
>   be different with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).

The destruction methods will be called after executing of other calls finished. Meaning your var_dump($i) will be called first, then destructions are executed.